# No Audio MPC MPD bluetooth speaker

Tags: pulseaudio

I can't get any audio from mpc. I can listen to sounds from websites.

[image: Screenshot from my Console]

I think I might need to edit the `etc/mpd.conf`

This might help as well:
[image]

Comment: Your image links aren't working.

Comment: I opened the question in another browser without being signed in and I can see them. Did you fix it? Are you still not seeing the pictures?

Comment: No, but I got an error message this time. Looks like whichever load balancer my part of the world sees for imgur is over capacity.

Comment: Please don't use images for text output. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the ALSA output to use the stereo jack

***/etc/mpd.conf***

```
audio_output {
        type            "alsa"
        name            "My ALSA Device"
}
```

Alternatively if you want to listen to music from your Android or IPhone or tablet you can setup the Streaming output. Then standard Apps can listen to your music from RPI by standard stream:

***/etc/mpd.conf***

```
audio_output {
       type            "httpd"
       name            "My HTTP Stream"
       encoder         "vorbis"                # optional, vorbis or lame
       port            "8000"
       bind_to_address "192.168.1.10"          # optional, IPv4 or IPv6
       quality         "5.0"                   # do not define if bitrate is defined
       bitrate         "128"                   # do not define if quality is defined
       format          "44100:16:1"
       max_clients     "0"                     # optional 0=no limit
}
```

**NOTE:** you can actually enable both outputs (ALSA + STREAM) at the same time.